# factory create method in C#?

Tags: c#, activex, factory-method

I am working on an API which supplies some ActiveX COM Object and I read these warning below:

> "You must use the factory “create” methods to create the COM objects in this section. Once a COM object has been created by a factory method, the COM object is tied to a corresponding TWS COM object (an instance of the COM object). Do not try to pass a COM object to another instance of a TWS COM object."

These words come from a part of VB example on this ActiveX API. Now I am using c#, what should I do to follow this rule?

Comment: Could you post the piece of code that is likely to make the warning be raised ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what any of these data types are or what you are naming these types, let's go with a data type called `ActiveXType` that is defined in `ApiComObject`.

```
class TwsCom {

  private ApiComObject apiComObject;

  public TwsCom() {
    apiComObject = new ApiComObject(); // create an instance, if required
  }
  // you might want to keep this variable type private to avoid breaking
  // the rules
  private ActiveXType NewActiveXType() {
    return apiComObject.Create();
  }

  public object SomeMethod() {
    ActiveXType activeX = NewActiveXType();
    return activeX.SomeMethod();
  }

}
```

This code is all very vague, but that's about the best I can do unless you'd like to provide more details.